# Adding arrays in json_encode and count them

Tags: php, json

I want to count all Arrays together but dont know my Problem

```
$output = array(
    'facebook'=> isset($finfo[0]) ? $finfo[0]->total_count : NULL,
    'twitter'=> isset($tinfo->count) ? $tinfo->count : NULL,
    'delicious'=> isset($dinfo[0]) ? $dinfo[0]->total_posts : NULL,
    'pinterest'=> isset($pinfo->count) ? $pinfo->count : NULL,
    'googlePlus'=> isset($gplus[0]['result']) ? $gplus[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] : NULL

);

function getSocialCount($output){
    return json_encode($output[facebook]) + json_encode($output[twitter]) + json_encode($output[pinterest]) + json_encode($output[googlePlus]);
}

<div>All: <?php echo getSocialCount(); ?></div>
```

Am I writing the Syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your function expects one parameter and you are not giving it any.

Change:

```
 <?php echo getSocialCount(); ?>
```

to:

```
 <?php echo getSocialCount($output); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks jeroen. 4 eyes see better than 2 eyes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add your array `$output` into your function..

`<?php echo getSocialCount($output); ?>`